# How to give strict validation to datepicker format in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using datepicker whose format is dd-mm-yyyy. But the problem is if someone enters date in other format, it accepts. For example, if someone enters date in yyyy-dd-mm or mm-dd-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd and so on, it accepts.

The Jquery function I am using is-

```js
$(function() {
 $('#date').datepick({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
```

The above code is just an basic idea for you.

I want if someone enters date in any other format apart from dd-mm-yyyy, it must prompt an alert and focus on that text box. How we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to use this field for exactly, however, the following HTML5 element may serve the purpose and requires no JS or libraries.

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" />
```

Swap the type from text to date.

UPDATE

You could use Jquery to check the value format using Regular Expression.

```js
$(function() {
 $('#date').datepick({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});
});

$('#date').on('change', function() {
    var givenValue = $('#date').val();
    if(!isValidDate(givenValue)){
      $('#date').val("");
      $("<p>Invalid</p>").insertAfter("#date");
    } else {
      $("<p>Valid</p>").insertAfter("#date");
    }
});

function isValidDate(input) {
  var regEx = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
  return input.match(regEx) != null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
```

You can then handle an invalid value however you like :)

Comment: (hit submit by mistake, damn)
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" />

Swap text for date

Comment: I am using datepicker in html5 text field, since date type is not supported by browsers except chrome